# Pyspark Phoenix integration failing in oozie workflow

Tags: pyspark, hbase, oozie, apache-phoenix

I am connecting and ingesting data into phoenix table using pyspark by below code

dataframe.write.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").mode("overwrite").option("table", "tablename").option("zkUrl", "localhost:2181").save()

When i run this in spark submit it works fine by below command,

```
spark-submit --master local --deploy-mode client --files /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/lib/phoenix-spark-4.7.0.2.6.3.0-235.jar:/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.3.0-235-client.jar" --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/lib/phoenix-spark-4.7.0.2.6.3.0-235.jar:/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.3.0-235-client.jar" sparkPhoenix.py
```

When i run this with oozie I am getting below error,

.ConnectionClosingException: Connection to ip-172-31-44-101.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.44.101:16020 is closing. Call id=9, waitTime=3 row 'SYSTEM:CATALOG,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=ip-172-31-44-101

Below is workflow,

```
<action name="pysparkAction" retry-max="1" retry-interval="1" cred="hbase">
<spark
xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">
<job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
<name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
<master>local</master>
<mode>client</mode>
<name>Spark Example</name>
<jar>sparkPhoenix.py</jar>
<spark-opts>--py-files Leia.zip --files /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/lib/phoenix-spark-4.7.0.2.6.3.0-235.jar:/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.3.0-235-client.jar --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/lib/phoenix-spark-4.7.0.2.6.3.0-235.jar:/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.3.0-235-client.jar</spark-opts>
</spark>
<ok to="successEmailaction"/>
<error to="failEmailaction"/>
</action>
```

Using spark-submit I got the same error I corrected that by passing required jars. In oozie, Even i pass jars, it throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

I found that "--files /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml" does not working when integrated with oozie. I pass the hbase-site.xml as below with file tag in oozie spark action. It works fine now

```
<file>file:///etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml</file>
```